# Changing httptransport tag in asp.net web.config during QA or Prod

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Web.config on dev calls a Web service on another remote dev server hence the binding looks like this

```
<binding name="XXXSoap12">
    <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576" allowCookies="false" 
        authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" 
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="1048576" 
        proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" 
        unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
</binding>
```

I want to change the `httpTransport` protocol/tag to `httpsTransport` protocol for QA, STG & PROD.

How do I write a transform for the same.

Answer (score 1):

In Web.Release.config (or Web.QA.config, or Web.STG.config, or another transform):

```
<binding name="XXXSoap12">

    <httpTransport xdt:Transform="Remove" />

    <httpsTransport xdt:Transform="Insert"
        manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576" allowCookies="false" 
        authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true"  
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="1048576" 
        proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" 
        unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true" />

</binding>
```

You can also [read this to learn more about config transforms](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889).